# generic that extends multiple classes in java

Tags: java, generics

I have Two classes:  User and UserDto. They are similar, like:

```
User {
int id;
get\set}

UserDto{
int id;
get\set}
```

And i have a method lets call it doSmth().
Is there a way to make this method work with both this classes as an input parameter like doSmth(User user)\doSmth(UserDto user) without overloading it?

I've tried to use generics like

```
    public <T extends User & UserDto> void doSmth(T user){
  System.out.println(user.getId);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Method for example does simple thing like

Comment: No, you can't. one class can never extend more than one interface. You can use composition, instead of inheritance, though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120046/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-generic-type-to-multiple-classes-in-java

Comment: `T extends User & UserDto` makes `T` the intersection type of the other two types. What you want is an union type instead. However, you can't do this in Java using generics. You have to use inheritance. See @Boris' answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. Create an interface `IUser` that declares the method `anOperation`, make both `User` and `UserDto` implement the same interface and then `doSmth(IUser)` can accept both `User` and `UserDto` calling the method `anOperation`